# Ecwid APIs to customize ecwid store

Tags: api, content-management-system, velo

I have integrated ECWID store in Wix site.
I want to change currency according to the location(country) of the user using Ecwid APIs,
So how can I do it and where should I code in Wixsite or Ecwid?

Answer (score 1):

It's Gunter from Ecwid team.

If you want to show different currencies to buyers on the storefront, you can use an existing app in App Market — Currency Converter. Here's a link to the app: https://www.ecwid.com/apps/design/currency-converter-app

If you'd like to program your own solution, you'll need to use, for example, [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API) to get the user's location. Then your custom JS will add a new element or change Ecwid's price to the visitor's currency.

Your JS that makes these changes can be added to the source code of the website where you have the Ecwid storefront or via a custom app. You can find more details on how to add custom JS in our documentation: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/customize-behaviour#add-custom-javascript

Also, you can change the store's currency via REST API. You'll need to utilize PUT "Update store profile" request. For example, to change the currency to United States Dollar you need to send a JSON body to your store's endpoint with the "currency" field equal to "USD".

Example of the endpoint: `https://app.ecwid.com/api/v3/13296841/profile?token=secret_tFb****`

Example of the body:

```
{
    "formatsAndUnits": {
        "currency": "USD"
}}
```

You can find more details in our documentation here: https://api-docs.ecwid.com/reference/store-profile#update-store-profile

Also, you can reach out to us directly via apps@ecwid.com

To get the token you need to log in as the store owner and then go to https://my.ecwid.com/#develop-apps page, there you can create an app and get its token. If you need to change anything in the app, just send us an email to apps@ecwid.com

Thank you!